# Download file from SFTP server and update DB using SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I have a file called SpeakerFiles.txt in SFTP server which has the following fields:

```
TRANS_ID | SPEAKER_ID | DOCUMENT_ID | TYPE | DOC_NAME
```

`SPEAKER_ID` and `DOCUMENT_ID` are the unique columns.

My local server database table(SpeakerFiles) has the following columns (DOC_PATH is extra column):

```
TRANS_ID | SPEAKER_ID | DOCUMENT_ID | TYPE | DOC_NAME | DOC_PATH
```

`DOC_NAME` might look something like `278_Biography_1011Biography.pdf` on the SFTP server.

**Problem:** I need to:

1. Go to path of that document
2. Download that document into our local server(specific path in local server)
3. Update that path(local server path) into our database

How can this be achieved using a SSIS package?

Answer (score 1):

1. For an SFTP connection, look into WinSCP or AlexFTPS client (there are more, those are just examples).
2. Building on step 1, use these assemblies in a Script Task to download the file, and store that local path in Package Variable.
3. Create a SQL Task to update your table using that variable written to in the previous step.