# Excel file transfer through SFTP to Sql Server database using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a user asking for the access to Production database such that he himself can import the excel in Production's table anytime he wants to, but I could not give him that.
So how can I do that using SSIS. Any idea like what should be the flow and should I use SFTP as SFTP is not supported by SSIS.

Comment: I was going the high and mighty route, but here is an answer to your question and not a diatribe. Have him put the file into a folder that he and Agent account have access to. And then schedule a job to run the SSIS package on a schedule of every x minutes. However, make sure that package does data quality checking before just dumping it into your production database. Your client will not take the blame if the DBA lets a bad excel file come through.

Comment: yes trying to do something like that only through WinScp @KeithL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download file from SFTP server and update DB using SSIS package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29200033/download-file-from-sftp-server-and-update-db-using-ssis-package)